# Full virtual desktop on iPad with sound

Tags: ipad, macos, audio, remote-desktop

Is there an iPad app that allows me to use a desktop game with an important audio component? I'm looking for a pleasurable music-like experience on the iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Splashtop](http://www.splashtop.com/) supports audio redirection (from the desktop to the iPad), however it requires running the Splashtop Streamer on your Mac.

Disclaimer: no affiliation with the company/product, just a satisfied user.

Comment: I've been using Splashtop for a few days now and it enables me to use my home PC when I am out and about with full audio streaming from the home PC. It works well on both external and internal networks

Answer (score 0):

While you play any game on the iPad, you can also play any song or playlist in your iTunes  song library at the same time, in the background.